# Spring remoting; JdkDynamicAopProxy with no methods

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, soap

**Some back story:** I'm in the process of setting up a test environment of an old(er) system (2008). The system is currently in working condition, but we need to start testing it before upgrading. There is a front-end proxy application interacting through Spring (2.5.4) HTTP invoking with a back-end application.

I have the source code and spring related dependencies in place, and I'm able to compile the system through build scripts shipped with the source code. I have set up a local VM acting as my back-end, and the applications are deployed and running on JBoss (4.2.2) on both sides.

I am able to run Soap requests to the proxy, authentication is working, so everything seems to be correct.

Now, the communication between applications through HTTP invoking does not work when I try to reach my servers services.

Here is my setup on the server side:

*This creates a bean that holds all of my related services*

```
<bean id="onlineService" class="my.own.class.OnlineService">
    <property name="orderService" ref="orderService" />
    <property name="invalidateService" ref="invalidateService" />
    <property name="checkStatusService" ref="checkStatusService" />
</bean>
```

*Exposing service using http invoker*

```
<bean name="onlineServiceHttp"
    class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter">
    <property name="service" ref="onlineService" />
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="my.own.interface.OnlineServiceI" />
</bean>
<bean id="simpleUrlMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/onlineServiceHttp">onlineServiceHttp</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is my client setup:

```
<!--  Online Service using HTTP Invoker -->
<bean id="onlineservice"
    class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl"
        value="http://${ONLINE_SERVICES_HOST}:8080/vmosvcs/vmoservice/onlineServiceHttp" />
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="my.own.interface.OnlineServiceI" />
</bean>
```

Finally, create my beans targeted through Soap on my client (the proxy application)

```
<bean id="orderMarshallEndpoint" class="my.proxy.endpoints.OrderMarshallEndpoint">
    <property name="service" ref="onlineservice" />
</bean>
<bean id="invalidateMarshallEndpoint" class="my.proxy.endpoints.InvalidateMarshallEndpoint">
    <property name="service" ref="onlineservice" />
</bean>
<bean id="checkStatusMarshallEndpoint" class="my.proxy.endpoints.CheckStatusMarshallEndpoint">
    <property name="service" ref="onlineservice" />
</bean>
```

When I send a Soap request towards for example checkStatusMarshallEndpoint, I get the following error on the client:

```
CustomAuthenticationManager 16 -----New Request in Proxy ----- 
CustomAuthenticationManager 17 Request sent by username :peter: 
CustomAuthenticationManager 19 Authentication Result:true: 
CheckStatusMarshallEndpoint 22 Check Status request received 
OnlineEndpoint 52 The authenticated partnerId is :imran 
CheckStatusMarshallEndpoint 27 The request is :: serial Number :null: activation Code :[PROTECTED]::imran 

CustomSoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver 28 org.springframework.remoting.RemoteInvocationFailureException: 
Invocation of method [public abstract RmiDataTransferObject OnlineServiceI.getServed(...,...)] 
failed in HTTP invoker remote service at [http://{ONLINE_SERVICE_HOST}:8080/vmosvcs/vmoservice/onlineServiceHttp]; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.getServed(..., ...)
```

at this spot

```
RmiDataTransferObject resp = service.getServed(getRequest(csr), OnlineServiceI.CHECK_STATUS_SERVICE);
```

where RmiDataTransferObject getServed(..., ...) is part of my.own.interface.OnlineServiceI. If I debug the execution, there is a JdkDynamicAopProxy declaring the correct HTTP path, but it has no methods registered. Only the intended interface.

What might I be missing? If I try the HTTP url in the browser, I get a 500, which indicate that the path is correct (something is mapped to that address).

Comment: Is that the actually message you get? If so your URL isn't translated correctly and that indicates that you are missing a placeholder configurer.

Comment: Yeah, that is the message / exception. I guess you refer to the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer (as I stated, I'm a real novice in the area). As I can see, the bean defined is:
 `<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
 </bean>`
This is defined in both the applications, with the same values.

Comment: Well judging from the stacktrce it isn't working...

Comment: I've noticed :). Thanks, it gives me some more search material. What I'm guessing, as the production code is working, is that there is something that is pointing towards the incorrect URL, deployment or otherwise. I'll keep digging.