# NoSuchMethod: Parameter comparisson differs. Same type, different object

Tags: java

I have two applications running on a server, and when I try to run a method through HttpInvoking, I get the following error:

```
CustomSoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver 28 org.springframework.remoting.RemoteInvocationFailureException: 
Invocation of method [public abstract RmiDataTransferObject OnlineServiceI.getServed(...,...)] 
failed in HTTP invoker remote service at [http://localhost:8080/vmosvcs/vmoservice/onlineServiceHttp]; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.getServed(..., ...)
```

This have been my reality for the past two weeks, and I'm starting to get frustrated. But today I found out, that the proxy object actually has a method named getServed, with the correct return and parameter types. But I was not finding it on the server...

Some debugging later I found my answer in this god forsaken method:

```
 private static boolean arrayContentsEq(Object[] a1, Object[] a2) {
    if (a1 == null) {
        return a2 == null || a2.length == 0;
    }

    if (a2 == null) {
        return a1.length == 0;
    }

    if (a1.length != a2.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        if (a1[i] != a2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is declared in Class.class (JDK 6), and is determining if the calling parameters are matching the host parameters. Nothing strange there.

But look at the 4:th if statement. Observing the arrays coming in, they do have same number of parameters, and the same type (observing this within the debug view in eclipse). The parameters are the correct ones, and consist of one of my objects (my.object.ObjectType) and one int. Upon comparing the parameter of my objecttype, it fails...

I'm no Java expert, but isn't that incorrect. That type of comparison will try to compare object addresses, not object types? It would be bound to fail, if I'm not comparing the same object with itself. And as it is a proxy object called through a http invokation, it is not possible to ensure that the parameters are the same object? Or am I greatly mistaken?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JdkAopDynamicProxy through HTTPInvokerProxyFactory: NoSuchMethod on proxy object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34991742/jdkaopdynamicproxy-through-httpinvokerproxyfactory-nosuchmethod-on-proxy-object)

Comment: please stop duplicating your own question: same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949118/spring-remoting-jdkdynamicaopproxy-with-no-methods) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949118/spring-remoting-jdkdynamicaopproxy-with-no-methods)

Comment: I'm sorry, but they are not really the same questions. Same area, and same problem, but different questions. This is regarding comparison in Java, and why calls to proxy objects seem to require the same objects as opposed to same object types regarding the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this was, as most of the times, dependency problems. I had two different versions of the object class in question (one in the war and one in the application server dependencies). So when it came down to compare the different object types, there were indeed two different instances of the same object class.

Well, it allowed me to dig down into the Class.class code, that is always fun.